# Which database fits with mark streams read/unread?

Tags: database, performance, architecture

I have a project that feed the line of streams into to page. After that each user open the stream, it marks the stream was read by that user. However user could mark unread to that stream.

So there are a lot of streams and users to do this event. I find the database or solution to fit to this situation. I think the database should be high read/write throughput and keep the data in key-value.

how the real-world do such as mail or group messenger.

Comment: For now, I use MongoDB to keep stream_id and user_id that make index in the collection. I don't know is it good for a long times?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit generic question. There are many ways (Design/Architecture/Technology) to accomplish your project. However in your case I don't think database selection is the primary problem. I would insist you to note few more functional & non-functional requirements, before evolving the solution. You should also consider various, trade-offs, pros & cons.

In between read this [article](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-building-facebook-messenger-for-windows/10150600868658920/), which should give you fair idea of how to start/approach.